# Windows socket completion routine callback after closesocket

Tags: windows, sockets, overlapped-io

While busy working with Windows Sockets in overlapped mode and using Completion routines (so no IOCP) for feedback I found the following curious case:

1. Open a server socket using `listen` and `AcceptEx`.
2. Connect a Client socket on said port using `ConnectEx`

We now have (at least) 3 sockets: 1 listing socket, a client connected socket and a server connected socket.

after transferring some data we close both the server and client connected sockets with `shutdown`. After this step both sockets are closed with `closesocket`.

Currently: just to be sure we have no pending completion routine I issue the following (pseudocode):

while SleepEx( 0, TRUE ) == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION do ;

I thought now it would be save to free the memory of the `OVERLAPPED` structures used by `WSARecv` and `WSASend`.

After this moment when the thread becomes in an alertable state again another completion routine callback is done for the server connected socket with an error 10053 but using the `OVERLAPPED` structure we just freed. This is use of memory after free.

Question:

When can you be sure no completion callbacks are issued anymore for a socket using overlapped IO using completion routines?

Comment: @RbMm: There's no IOCP here.

Comment: @BenVoigt - but how about `AcceptEx` and `ConnectEx` ? only way use it in asynchronous mode - bind socket for iocp. unclear what is OP doing

Comment: @RbMm: You can do asynchronous I/O just fine without completion ports.

Comment: @BenVoigt - depend from api. `AcceptEx` and `ConnectEx` alow asynchronous only with iocp. no APC option for this api, no callback here as parameter. are not ? or OP use synchronous `AcceptEx` and `ConnectEx` ?

Comment: @RbMm: No callback but there's an event handle in the overlapped structure.  And the actual operation causing him problems is the `WSARecv` which does have a callback parameter.

Comment: @BenVoigt - yes, but use events very uncomfortable - need have unique event for every io request (so usually create/close events), then - when event signaled - need somehow manually get from event pointer to overlapped (need use some map for this). because this i very not like events completion. however i first wrong read question, and your answer is correct

Comment: @RbMm: Only *concurrent* I/O requests need distinct events.  For example if you're just streaming data from a serial port (so that each time a read completes, you issue a new overlapped read) then the new read can reuse the same OVERLAPPED and hEvent (and if you like, data buffer) as the completed one.  Also, the return value from `(Msg)WaitForMultipleObjects(Ex)` is useful for finding which operation completed.

Comment: @RbMm: So yeah, for a web server with a variable number of simultaneous clients, completion ports are definitely the way to go.  But for a desktop app with exactly one connection to a server, exactly one connection to a log file, exactly one connection to a local serial peripheral... overlapped I/O with fixed indexes works very smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the I/O completion (closing the socket will cancel outstanding requests and you will get a completion callback).

The OS has ownership of the OVERLAPPED structure and associated buffer until you synchronize on event completion (by waiting for the `hEvent` or receiving an APC).  You cannot do anything with the buffer until you receive this callback, and you definitely must not free it.  Wait for the OS to tell you it is no longer needed.

Note that cancellations don't necessarily cause completion immediately, because the driver may be synchronizing with hardware requests and only mark the IRP complete when the hardware state changes.  (This would be necessary if DMA is in use but might be done for other operations just for consistency)  So the `SleepEx` loop you showed is not guaranteed to collect all cancellations.

Keep track for each socket of the pending operations, and use `WaitForSingleObjectEx` instead of `SleepEx`, to wait explicitly for each one.

Comment: Ok. So for each outstanding WSARecv and WSASend I keep a bookkeeping and when the callbacks have returned can I cleanup the overlapped structures and the socket wrapper object. But this means there must be a guarantee that the callback will be called or else I might wait indefinitely for the callback and hence will have a memory leak instead. I could not find if this is guaranteed by the OS. Is this guaranteed?

Comment: If you got `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` from the initial call, you are guaranteed to get the callback when the operation ends, whether success, failure, or cancellation.

Comment: From MSDN: both an 0 (OK) and WSAEWOULDBLOCK returns a callback guaranteed. So bookkeeping it is.